# Twilio: count number of SMS messages in the log from a specific number using Node.js

Tags: node.js, logging, twilio, sms

I'm trying to write a Twilio server-side function (https://console.twilio.com/us1/develop/functions/classic) in Node.js to count the number of incoming messages from any sender.

If the number is = 0, do X.

If the number is > 0, do Y.

Obviously the code below doesn't work, and may even be wildly off. The resulting error message is: "{"message":"username is required","name":"Error","stack":"Error: username is required\n    at new Twilio (/var/task/node_modules/twilio/lib/rest/Twilio.js:141:11)"

Any assistance is appreciate. Thanks!

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    // 
    const accountSid = process.env.TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID;
    const authToken = process.env.TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN;
    const client = require('twilio')(accountSid, authToken);
    //
    //const Phone = event.Phone;
    
    client.messages
          .list({
             from: event.Phone
           })
          .then(messages => messages.forEach(m => console.log(m.sid)));
    //
    if(messages.length === 0)
    {
        return callback(null,"Continue");
    } else {
        //
        return callback("Error","Error");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

First up, can I recommend you use a [Twilio Functions Service](https://console.twilio.com/us1/develop/functions/services?frameUrl=%2Fconsole%2Ffunctions%2Foverview%2Fservices%3Fx-target-region%3Dus1), not classic Functions.

Your error message suggests to me that your `accoundSid` is blank. Within Twilio Functions, your Account Sid and Auth Token are saved as the environment variables `ACCOUNT_SID` and `AUTH_TOKEN` and should be accessed on the `context` object rather than `process.env`. To make things easier, you can create a client using `context.getTwilioClient()` instead.

Once you've fixed that, there will still be more to do as the call to `client.messages.list` is asynchronous, so you should not `callback` until that API request is complete.

Try something like this instead:

```js
exports.handler = function (context, event, callback) {
  const client = context.getTwilioClient();

  client.messages
    .list({
      from: event.Phone,
    })
    .then((messages) => {
      messages.forEach((m) => console.log(m.sid));
      if (messages.length === 0) {
        return callback(null, "Continue");
      } else {
        return callback(null, "Error");
      }
    })
    .catch(error => callback(error));
};
```

Comment: Phil, thanks for taking the time to answer my question! I also received a response back from Twilio, which I will post below.

Answer (score 0):

From Twilio support, which aligns with Phil's answer:

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
 // Make sure under the Functions Global Config tab:
 // "Add my Twilio Credentials (ACCOUNT_SID) and (AUTH_TOKEN) to ENV" is CHECKED
 const client = context.getTwilioClient();
 
 const phoneNumber = event.From_Number;

 client.messages
    .list({ from: phoneNumber, limit:20 })
    .then((result) => {
    console.log(result.length);
    return callback(null, result);
 })
    .catch((error) => {
    console.error(error);
    return callback(error, null);
 });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The version of the answer I'm actually using:

```
exports.handler = function (context, event, callback) {
  //
  const client = context.getTwilioClient();
  //
  client.messages
    .list({
      from: event.Phone,
    })
    .then((messages) => {
      // messages.forEach((m) => console.log(m.sid));
      if (messages.length <= 1) {
        console.log("The number of previous messages is " + messages.length);
        return callback(null, "Continue");
      } else {
        return callback("The number of previous messages is " + messages.length);
      }
    })
    .catch(error => callback(error));
};
```